# OffsetDateTime always converted to UTC

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm having a very simple spring boot app that gets and returns a timestamp.

The code is as follow:

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @PostMapping("/")
    public Model test(@RequestBody Model model) {
        return model;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Model {
    public OffsetDateTime timestamp;
}
```

I've noticed that when I'm sending timezones which are not UTC the object I'm receiving converted into UTC - for example, the following call:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2017-07-21T17:32:28+01:00"
}
```

has this response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2017-07-21T16:32:28Z"
}
```

Is there a way to disable this behavior and receive the time as it was send?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but could you use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)?

Comment: I actually receive this as auto-generated code from OpenApi3 spec so I have very little control over the object itself

Comment: How do you know `2017-07-21T17:32:28+01:00` is the value before serialize ? Do you try to specify timezone using jackson annotation ?

Comment: I don't understand the question - I'm sending the request to the service so I know it was originally `+01:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because Jackson is using context default timezone when deserializing.
In Spring-Boot you can disable this quite easily, by just adding:

`spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone=false`

to your application.properties.